# Clear cookies in QWebEngineView

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt, pyqt5

How to clear cookies in PyQt5?
I tried following code:

```
QWebEngineCookieStore.deleteAllCookies()
```

And I got an error:

```
TypeError: deleteAllCookies(self): first argument of unbound method must have type 'QWebEngineCookieStore'
```

I've added braces:

```
QWebEngineCookieStore().deleteAllCookies()
```

But got an error again:

```
TypeError: PyQt5.QtWebEngineCore.QWebEngineCookieStore cannot be instantiated or sub-classed
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

QWebEngineCookieStore can not be created, what you have to do is obtain it from the QWebEngineProfile as I show below:

```
QWebEngineProfile.defaultProfile().cookieStore().deleteAllCookies()
```